# How do I use Regular Expression to match multiple elements in one line of string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am a regex novice.  I am performing this code in PowerShell, but it's not PowerShell syntax I need help with.

I am trying to match multiple elements in one line of string.  I want regex to identify all the specific elements, not just one.

For example, in the strings `Video1.2000.1080p.BluRay.x264` or `Video2.1990.720p.DVD.x264`, I want regex to identify the year, the resolution (720p or 1080p), **and** the encoding (x264) of the string.

Here are the regex patterns I have tried to no avail:

```
(\d{4})(\d{3,4}p)(x\d{3})

\d{4}|\d{3,4}p|x\d{3}

\d{4}|\d{3}p|\d{4}p|x\d{3}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are the patterns consistent? are they _strings_ or are they file objects?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes the patterns are consistent and only strings.

Comment: thank you for the info! ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression is likely to find our desired outputs:

```
^[^.]+\.(\d{4})\.(\d{3,4}p)\.[A-Za-z]+\.(x\d{3})$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ddnRvH/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/ddnRvH/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I was using Regex Pal.  In fact when I [plugged in your recommended code into Regex Pal](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=110588), it didn't find anything.  But If I removed the `$` anchor at the end, it matched.  Thanks for the suggestion.
The regex visualizer is great.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into an array too:

```
$array = 'Video1.2000.1080p.BluRay.x264'.split('.')
```

Comment: I was using an array and performing a search on the array before.  But I figure that is slower, and more code to write, than just using regex.

Answer (score 0):

since you don't make it clear if these strings are strings OR file objects, i presume that they are strings. [*grin*] in that case, you can simply split on the `.` and use that. PoSh can do "serial assignment" [i dunno what the real name is [*blush*]], so the split results can be immediately assigned to $Vars.

the `$Results` collection will have custom objects that you can neatly save to a CSV or display to the screen. you can get the individual values via `$Results[$IndexNumber].Year` ... so that means `$Results[3].Year` would give you `1967`.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
Video1.2000.1080p.BluRay.x264
Video2.1990.720p.DVD.x264
Panama Red.1985.420p.LaserDisk.x264
Mary Jane Rides Again.1967.666p.VCD.y666
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $Name, $Year, $Resolution, $Format, $Encoding = $IS_Item.Split('.')

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $Name
        SourceName = $IS_Item
        Year = $Year
        Resolution = $Resolution
        Format = $Format
        Encoding = $Encoding
        }
    }

$Results
```

truncated output ...

```
Name       : Video1
SourceName : Video1.2000.1080p.BluRay.x264
Year       : 2000
Resolution : 1080p
Format     : BluRay
Encoding   : x264

[*...snip...*] 

Name       : Mary Jane Rides Again
SourceName : Mary Jane Rides Again.1967.666p.VCD.y666
Year       : 1967
Resolution : 666p
Format     : VCD
Encoding   : y666
```

Comment: The title of my post says it's a string.  And the body of my post mentions it's a string.  Not sure how you could claim it's not clear.  Also, I didn't want to use an array, as it is more code.  I figure regex would be faster.

Comment: @howdoicode - since it LOOKS Like a file name, there was every reason to presume that your source was a list of file _objects_ that simply _look like strings_. thus my question [*grin*] ///// as for the array of outputs ... that is simply for convenience - it's a neatly packaged way to handle a number of results. you can simply use the one line that does all the work - the `.Split('.')` line - to get the same result for a single item.